# Which way of starting a new activity is the best?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my learning process of Android Development, I have come across two different ways of starting a new activty. And now I start to wonder.

They both work fine. However, I wanna know if one of the options is better to use, and why?

My first example (and the one that I so far like the most):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
```

And the second:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.MENUSCREEN"));
```

Where I need to add the android:name to my intent-filter in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.MainMenuActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.MENUSCREEN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And have I understood i correct, that an intent is like saying, that I intent to do something? An "intention" to do an action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to answer your question:

> Which way of starting a new activity is the best?

Depends on what you want to do and where the activity you want to start actually lives, just to make a long story short, Intent can be separated in two types Explicit/Implicit.

The first one you are trying:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Is "Explicit", it means you have access to the class that will actually handle the intent it self, usually that's only possible if the class is somewhere in your project, but that's not always the case, sometimes you might need to open an Activity from a different application and then you would use the second option.

The second you tried:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.MENUSCREEN"));
```

Is "Implicit", this is an action that any activity that fits the "action/category/data" intent filter will be able to handle, if more than one Activity can handle it, the operating system would pop up a window to ask the user to select one of them.

As you can see one way is no better than the other, it all depends on what you want to do and the possibilities the OS give you to be able to start activities under different circumstances.

Hope it Helps!

Regards!

Comment: Thank you for your time. This helped me to understand it perfectly! :-)

Comment: @Adnaves : To expand on this - adding an `<intent-filter>` to your `Activity` in the manifest is actually discouraged unless you need it to be accessible from other apps. If you only need to start the `Activity` from your own app then remove the `<intent-filter>` and always use an explicit `Intent`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent helpIntent = new Intent(this, HowToPlay.class);
this.startActivity(helpIntent);
```

Will always start `HowToPlay` activity.

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.example.MENUSCREEN"));
```

Will start *an* activity that can handle the given intent. If there is more than one activity that can handle the intent, the system will show a dialog for the user to pick which one they would use.

Use the first one if you want to start exactly the specific activity, use the second if you just want to start something that can handle the action, and you don't care about what that something is (e.g. opening a webpage, you don't care what browser the user is using).